# Where can I download NVIDIA drivers for mobile GPUs from?

Tags: drivers

I have an HP DM3T with NVIDIA GeForce G105m and I am trying to install Windows XP on the notebook. Since HP doesn't offer drivers for Windows XP I am forced to look for drivers on the manufacturer website.

For strange reasons NVIDIA doesn't offer drivers for mobile chipsets on its site (I wonder why?). Does anyone know where to get those drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked the UK version of the nVidia site and on the downloads page there is an option to select the 100M series. Are these the ones you're looking for?

There's also an option to automatically find drivers. Have you tried that option?

Comment: strange but i was able to download the drivers from the uk site while they were not available on usa site.

Answer (score 2):

Get the modified drivers from [LaptopVideo2Go](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/25697-v19555-windows-xp-32bit-nvidia-oem/). Please note: The drivers are "modified" by means of an updated `inf` file only, no binary changes. I can vouch for these drivers as I have been using them for the past 2 years for my 8600m GT on Dell Inspiron 1520. If the setup doesn't detect the card then extract them to a folder, download the modified inf file and replace the`nv4_disp.inf`file with this one, and re-run the installer.

Answer (score 1):

nvidia's [Notebook Graphics Drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_drivers.html) website should help you out.  You can do an [automatic scan](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx?lang=en-us) which should detect the correct drivers for your machine.

You must have [Java](http://java.com) installed in order to run the scan.

Comment: tried automatic scan and it didnt find anything